# Shorter validation function for required fields

Tags: javascript, html, validation, typescript

In a HTML application with typescript I have a HTML form. This form has some required fields. In my typescript file I'm building an error message like this:

```
hasErrors() {
    let errorCount = 0;

    if (!item.Field1()) {
        this.ErrorText('"Field1"');
        errorCount++;
    }
    if (!item.Field2()) {
        if (errorCount > 0)
            this.ErrorText(this.ErrorText() + ', "Field2"');
        else
            this.ErrorText('"Field2"');
        errorCount++;
    }
    if (!item.Field3()) {
        if (errorCount > 0)
            this.ErrorText(this.ErrorText() + ', "Field3"');
        else
            this.ErrorText('"Field3"');
        errorCount++;
    }

    // ...

    if (errorCount > 1)
        this.ErrorText("The fields " + this.ErrorText() + " are required.";
    else if (errorCount == 1)
        this.ErrorText("The field " + this.ErrorText() + " is required.";
    else
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

As you can see, this function gets very long if there are many fields that are required. Is there any better / shorter way to get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function catErrors(field){
    if (!item.field) {
        if (this.errorCount > 0)
            this.ErrorText(this.ErrorText() + ', "' + field + '"');
        else
            this.ErrorText('"' + field + '"');
        this.errorCount++;
    }
}
```

Could you possibly create a function that looks for the errors?
You would call the function like this: `catErrors(Field1)`.
It would help to shorten your code. All you have to do is add the first field manually to start off and everything following it would use the function `catErrors()`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This will show Default require msg

```
  <form action="includes/loginprocess.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" required>
    <input type="password"name="pass" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Come to think about it, you are trying to tell users which blanks they are missing. Is it really needy? How about detecting any missing blank and returning the message "Field xxx is missing"? For example, you have two blanks, username and password, if user doesn't fill in neither of them, it's ok that you only point out "Username is required."